# Append all array values to another property using phing

Tags: php, for-loop, properties, append, phing

How can I make this on phing?

```
foreach (array as values) {
    $data .= $values
}
```

something like that. Appending all the array values on property name $data.

Answer (score -3):

suppose   you have array

```
<?php
      $array1;
    foreach($array1 as values)
      {
         $data .= $values
      }
?>
```

Comment: Several syntax errors actually, missing semicolons and variable prefixes

Comment: its not about the syntax issues on sample code. its about how you understand the sample code. thanks anyway.